# Is it possible to attain absolute 0 temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, thermal-conductivity

I think it is ***impossible*** to attain this  temperature in normal circumstances.

> ***As energy would be applied from surrounding areas and energy flow from higher to lower potential and hence all the heat will move and increase the temperature and it is not possible to get a container with ***infinite*** insulation.***

But Can it be done in an abstract way like the abstract parallel universe is there. If the above statement is wrong, so is it ***possible*** to do it, if yes then please tell how?

I have seen about the question regarding vacuum. It describes the case correctly though I still want to know is there anything (except vacuum as it isn't the one that satisfies the condition.) Is there any way to create conditions even if we don't have the technology right now to attain absolute 0 temperature.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is absolute zero possible in a complete vacuum?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/398171/)

Comment: @Cross I have edited the question. Check now.

Comment: No, on ecannot attain the absolute zero, but one can approach very closely to it. I don't know what is the record of low temperature these days by micro- and nano-Kelvin temperatures are routinely used in laboratory experiments.

Comment: @RogerVadim I read from the thread shared by cross and I think it is not possible as if we even bring an absolute 0 temperature body near a warm body then they would reach an equilibrium but Is it possible, son place in space has absolute 0 temperature. And how close we can get to the absolute 0 temperature if we have body of absolute 0 temperature (imagine) to bring some other object's temperature to absolute 0 temperature so basically would it be possible to clone the temperature.

Comment: @RogerVadim Can you please describe the equation and the meaning of the variables with the constant h and a dash over it. if you can tell me how to prove it also?

Comment: @RogerVadim And can you also tell is it possible that the absolute 0 temperature collects all the energy from universe when it is ending and concentrate it once more to give it life again . All to reach equilibrium and our universe will never end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, one cannot attain the absolute zero, but one can approach very closely to it. I don't know what is the record of low temperature these days by micro- and nano-Kelvin temperatures are routinely used in laboratory experiments.

Cooling an object means subtracting from it the smaller and smaller quantities of energy. Thus, according to the energy uncertainty relation $\Delta E \Delta t\geq \hbar$ - that is, the closer one approaches to zero, the longer it takes. Time of an experiment cannot be possibly longer than the lifetime of the Universe.

Note that temperature is well-defined only for macroscopic collections of objects. Thus, when devising experiments for cooling, it is important that temperature remains temperature. There are many cases where ***effective temperature*** is defined, leading to alleged thermodynamic paradoxes, which are really due to different meaning of the temperature (e.g., lasers are often characterized by a negative temperature, and zero temperature is not a stretch of imagination in this case).

Comment: Negative temperature what is that, is that like-40°C?

Comment: Can you please describe the equation and the meaning of the variables with the constant h and a dash over it. if you can tell me how to prove it also?

Comment: And can you also tell is it possible that the absolute 0 temperature collects all the energy from universe when it is ending and concentrate it once more to give it life again . All to reach equilibrium and our universe will never end.

Comment: $\hbar$ is the *Planck's constant and the energy-time uncertainty relation is an example of a Heisenbreg uncertainty relation - you can read about both in WIkipedia. I suppose you have never studied quantum mechanics?

Comment: Yes, quantan mechanical laws are new to me

Comment: I would be grateful if you tell the answer to:-  And can you also tell is it possible that the absolute 0 temperature collects all the energy from universe when it is ending and concentrate it once more to give it life again . All to reach equilibrium and our universe will never end.