# Does the second law of thermodynamics put limit on efficiency of engines?

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics it is claimed that the efficiency of no engine can be one. But look at the efficiency of let's say Carnot engine $\eta=1-T_c/T_h$. Now one can take $T_c$ arbitrarily close to absolute zero then make the efficiency of the engine close to one?
So indeed it is possible to have efficiency at least close to one !!?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137030/when-the-low-temperture-reservoir-with-negative-temperture-kelvin-such-as-isi

Comment: Close to 1 is not the same as exactly 1.

Answer (score 1):

The second law just says that the efficiency of any engine operating between two reservoirs with temperature $T_H$ and $T_C$ cannot exceed the Carnot efficency 
$$e_c=1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}$$.

Besides, $T_C$ cannot be zero by the third law of thermodynamics.

Also, in principle the efficiency can be greater than $1$ if temperature can be negative.

However, in that case the definition of $$\text{efficiency}=\frac{W}{Q_H}$$ may not make sense.