# Energy of single particles, measured in kelvin?

Tags: cosmic-rays

[This page](http://www.physlink.com/education/askexperts/ae254.cfm) says cosmic photons have an energy of 2.78 kelvin, so how much energy would the particles that show up in a bubble chamber have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The cosmic-ray tag wiki](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/cosmic-rays/info) already explains this:

> Usually referring to stable high energy elementary particles - cosmic
>   rays were found to arrive the Earth from galactic and extragalactic
>   sources and interact with the atmosphere. The energies of this
>   particles are one of their prominent features and extend over multiple
>   orders of magnitude, at least up to $10^{20}eV$.

So going by [this table](http://www.saha.ac.in/theory/palashbaran.pal/conv.html), that's widely about 1.0E20 / 1E9 = 1.0E11 GeV, so 1.0E11 * 1.16E13 = $1.16^{24}K$. Enough to [boil](http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/EN/units-converter/energy/1-65/joule-kelvin/) 5E-7 [liters of 25 degree Celsius water](https://www.quora.com/How-much-energy-is-needed-to-boil-water-How-much-energy-would-it-take-to-boil-1-liter-of-water/answer/Diwas-Adhikari).

Comment: Of course, a single particle does not have a temperature. The cosmic microwave background is a thermal distribution of many photons with a temperature of 2.78K.

Comment: What about a basketball-sized amount of them, all heading this way with the same energy?

Comment: Temperature is a statistical measurement. All particles having the same energy is not a thermal distribution, so you cannot define a temperature. They have energy, sure, but not a temperature.

Comment: But this is not a typical "particle that shows up in a bubble chamber". By many orders of magnitude.

Comment: There is no reason you can't use Kelvin as a energy scale (the size of the unit is just set by Boltzmann's constant), but it is rarely done unless there is a system that can reasonable be described as having a temperature involved somehow. Particle energies are not generally described that way, unless you are talking about thermal neutrons (which average about 1/40 eV of kinetic energy at room temperature).