# Upper bound for the Kelvin scale

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no absolute maximum temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/why-is-there-no-absolute-maximum-temperature)

On the Kelvin scale, absolute zero represents the temperature at which there is no thermal motion. Consequently, speaking of $-r$ Kelvin has no physical meaning for any positive real number $r$.
My question is this: is there a value $k>0$ that is an upper bound for the Kelvin scale in the sense that speaking of $k+r$ Kelvin has no physical meaning for any positive real number $r$?
Presumably there is such a $k$, based on "finite" energy, but is it so incomprehensibly large that it is no longer possible to distinguish between one level of largeness from another, say in the sense of [Friedman](http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/finiteseq10_8_98.pdf).

Comment: Yes/no/maybe http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/physics/absolute-hot.html