# Is there/could there be a theoretical absolute hot?

Tags: temperature

We know there is a theoretical absolute zero (0K) at which particles have no kinetic energy, but is there an absolute hot at which a particle can be given no more kinetic energy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an upper limit to temperature in thermodynamics or statistical mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109738/)

Comment: See also [Why is there no absolute maximum temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1775/)

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article [Absolute hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_hot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highest temperature limit now is currently thought to be the temperature at the Big Bang.Because the temperature greater than the big bang would mean to create something that was present in Planck era which we don't know much about.Plus,nothing observed in the universe till now is more hotter.

A good competitor would be the core of a supernova though.
Also ,you can see http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/BBhistory.html

Laws of physics breakdown at that temperature above the Planck temperature of $10^{32}$ K so thus it's considered theoretically the highest temperature up to which we can measure.