# What is highest temperature which is attainable?

Tags: temperature

We all know that there is a limit to the lowest temperature which can be achieved i.e. $0K$.
But I wanted to know if there is a limit to the highest temperature which can be attained.
And if there is a limit, what is that temperature?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1775/2451 and links therein. Concerning lowest temperature, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21851/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Perhaps it is interesting to cite [this very recent development](http://www.physik.uni-augsburg.de/theo1/hanggi/Sokolov_news.pdf) concerning negative temperatures.

Comment: @Qmechanic I do think so.

Comment: But please note that negative temperatures are really kind of "higher than infinite" rather than lower than zero in the sense in which we know -- it happens only in systems in which the energy is bounded but the entropy can still increase past the upper bound of the energy.