# Maximum Temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, thermal-radiation

I have been reading a lot about wavelengths of light and Planck's law and such. Curious as to whether a minimum wavelength of $h$ (Planck's Constant) indicates that there is in some way an absolute maximum temperature.

Any thoughts or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1775/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Planck temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_temperature) is the maximum temperature on the Planck scale. Some sources call it [absolute hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_hot).

The Planck temperature is defined as
$$T_P = \frac{m_P c^2}{k} = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar c^5}{G k^2}} = 1.416833(85)\times10^{32} \text{K}$$
where
$m_P$ is the Planck mass, $c$ is the speed of light, $\hbar = h/2\pi$ is the reduced Planck constant, $k$ is Boltzmann's constant, and $G$ is the universal gravitational constant.

Comment: Please do not paste images of equations on this site. Write them out. You can click the edit button to see how it works, or look in the [help center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation). I fixed it for you this time, but next time please do it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @DanielSank I didn't have the time to write it out, but had planned on it.

Comment: what would happen if we could make a laser with Planck Temperature ? could we cut anything in the universe ?