# Is there an upper limit to temperature in the universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, temperature, universe

The [Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun)'s core temperature has been modelled to be $\approx 1.57 \times 10^7$ K

In [supernovae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova):

"In lower mass cores the collapse is stopped and the newly formed neutron core has an initial temperature of about 100 billion kelvin, 6,000 times the temperature of the sun's core. At this temperature, neutrino-antineutrino pairs of all flavours are efficiently formed by thermal emission." (1)

Also:

"[In supernovae] the core temperature rises to over 100 billion degrees as the iron atoms are crushed together." (2)

**Question**: Does temperature in the universe have an upper limit, like the lower limit of absolute zero? What’s the highest temperature possible in the universe?

References:

(1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova

(2) https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/objects/supernovae1.html

Comment: Immediately after the Big Bang it was substantially hotter (but cooled quickly as it expanded).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1775/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score -1):

The highest temperatures in the universe are at the center of [black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole), but we don't have a theory which describes what happens at the singularity, so nobody knows if the temperature there is finite or infinite.

Comment: If we don't have a theory, how can we even estimate the temperature?

Comment: Because we are applying GR to the singularity but we know that GR cannot be entirely correct(quantum effects take place)there.

Comment: @JonCuster "If we don't have a theory, how can we even estimate the temperature?".When did that stop us?We had estimated the heat capacity of solids way before quantum mechanics was discovered using classical molecular kinetic theory.At moderate temperatures we knew experimentally that the classical molecular kinetic theory gives somewhat correct results.Its when things get too cold or too hot that there is a difference between the quantum mechanical theory and the classical theory.